# Update with join takes long time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-performance

I have a problem updating a table. I'm running the following query:

```
UPDATE Table1 SEt entrena = c.Count 
FROM Table1 AS p INNER JOIN (
SELECT e.EmplID, COUNT(e.EmplID ) as Count 
FROM Table2 AS e WHERE e.Start >= @Start AND e.Start <=@End 
GROUP BY e.EmplID ) AS c ON p.EmplID = c.EmplID
WHERE P.Date  = '2050-12-31'
```

The Table1 has 12000 rows and the select inside the join get only 51 rows but the update takes around 2 minutes, but if I delete the where clase p.date = '2050-12-31' the update takes less than a second. And I can't figure out how to solve it. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Both tables don't have indexes.

Comment: Can you provide your indexes?

Comment: Are Start and EmplId on Table2 indexed?

Comment: Both tables don't have indexes.

Comment: why do you repeatedly add the C# tag? `C#` has nothing to do with this, it's purely a `sql server / sql` question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your query:

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET entrena = c.Count 
    FROM Table1 p INNER JOIN
         (SELECT e.EmplID, COUNT(e.EmplID ) as Count 
          FROM Table2 e
          WHERE e.Start >= @Start AND e.Start <=@End 
          GROUP BY e.EmplID
         ) c
    ON p.EmplID = c.EmplID
    WHERE P.Date  = '2050-12-31';
```

First, you need to change the first line to:

```
UPDATE p
```

when you define an alias in the `from` clause, you need to use that in the `update` for the right thing to happen.  (I wish your query generated an error in SQL Server, but it does not.)

To optimize this query, you want to add indexes.  I would suggest these two:

```
Table1(date, EmplID)
Table2(EmplId, Start)
```

You may then find that the correlated subquery version is faster, particularly if the `where` clause is highly selective:

```
UPDATE p
    SET entrena = (SELECT COUNT(e.EmplID ) as Count 
                   FROM Table2 e
                   WHERE e.Start >= @Start AND e.Start <=@End AND
                         p.EmplID = e.EmplID
                  )
    FROM Table1 p
    WHERE P.Date  = '2050-12-31';
```

However, I suspect that the `p` versus `table1` is the root of your performance problem.